# How can i convert a string to tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

i have read a string from csv_file  given below

```
"('Who is Shaka Khan?',{'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}),"
```

when i iterate over it, I get each character as:

```
('(', "'", 'W', 'h', 'o', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'k', 'a', ' ', 'K', 'h', 'a', 'n', '?', "'", ',', '{', "'", 'e', 'n', 't', 'i', 't', 'i', 'e', 's', "'", ':', ' ', '[', '(', '7', ',', ' ', '1', '7', ',', ' ', "'", 'P', 'E', 'R', 'S', 'O', 'N', "'", ')', ']', '}', ')', ',')
```

but i need it to be stored in tuple form so  when i iterate over it i can get output as given below

```
 Who is Shaka Khan?

{'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}
```

how can i do this in python?

Comment: I am not sure but please try this once : `a = ' who is Shaka Khan' print tuple(a,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string to a tuple.

```
>>> s = "('Who is Shaka Khan?',{'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]})," 
>>> import ast
>>> t = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> t[0]
('Who is Shaka Khan?', {'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]})
>>> t[0][0]
'Who is Shaka Khan?'
>>> t[0][1]
{'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}
```

Optionally, you can convert it to a dict for easy access

```
>>> d = dict(ast.literal_eval(s))
>>> d['Who is Shaka Khan?']
{'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `literal_eval`,

```
In [87]: from ast import literal_eval

In [88]: literal_eval("('Who is Shaka Khan?',{'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}),")
Out[88]: (('Who is Shaka Khan?', {'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}),)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
a = ast.literal_eval("('Who is Shaka Khan?',{'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}),")
print(a[0][1])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}
```

Answer (score -1):

> you have to use the tuple function, but it has to be a list beforehand

## Example:

```
l = [4,5,6]
tuple(l)
```

> RETURNS
>       (4, 5, 6)

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to the question?

Comment: Hello, nice to see you again @Roganjosh. So i felt like this question was a little hard to understand, but from what i got out of it, it seemed to me like what he asked was "How can i convert a string to tuple in python" as the title states, allthough he also asks how to create iterate over it, which some one else got to before me